# 'str' object is not callable error while using 'Find an element' by link text or XPATH in Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, find

I'm new to coding and trying to learn Selenium with Python. I want the download button to be clicked, but am getting the error"'Str' object not callable".Using Python 3.10 and Selenium 4.1.3

Here is my code:

```
import os

from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

os.environ['PATH'] += r"C:\SeleniumDrivers"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://www.python.org/downloads")

driver.implicitly_wait(10)

my_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH("//a[contains(@href,'Download Python 3.10.4')]"))

my_element.click()
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You want to click on the "Download Python" button right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you wanted to click on "Download Python"`. If yes then this code does the job,

```
my_element = driver.find_element(by = By.XPATH, value = "//*[@id='touchnav-wrapper']/header/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/p/a")
my_element.click()
```

Your code has two problems -

1. You did this `By.XPATH("//a[contains(@href,'Download Python 3.10.4')]")`. Here `By.XPATH` is not actually a function but just a variable with the value "XPATH", so you can't pass parameters in it. That's why you got the **'str' object is not callable** error. For XPATHs you need to use something like this `driver.find_element(by = By.XPATH, value = <XPATH>)`.
2. Even if what you did above was correct, the XPATH you were passing was incorrect. The correct XPATH is `my_element = driver.find_element(by = By.XPATH, value = "//*[@id='touchnav-wrapper']/header/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/p/a")`.

Comment: could you please tell me how different the code will be if i've to use link text?

Comment: I have never used partial link text before so am not the best guy to ask it about. But I'll answer this question in a few days once I learn it, don't worry!